# load a file from a folder and save to another one

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

I'm writing with visual c++ using opencv (2.3 version) and qt (4.8 version) and I have some problems with loading files (jpg images) from a folder and saving to another one. Here's my code:

```
for (uint i = 0; i < numFiles; i += (numFiles / numBoards) ){

    QString str = "D:/TESI_Magistrale/Linescanner/imm_aquisition/image" + QString::number(i + 1) + ".jpg";
    QImage *image=new QImage();
    image->load(str);


    IplImage *currentImage = cvCreateImageHeader(cv::Size(640,480),IPL_DEPTH_8U,1);//1 channel xk b&w (solo brightness)
    currentImage->imageData = (char*)image;

    QString str1 = "D:/TESI_Magistrale/Linescanner/imm_calibration/image" + QString::number(i + 1) + ".jpg";
    QByteArray ba1 = str1.toLatin1();
    const char *text1 = ba1.data();
    cvSaveImage(text1,currentImage);


}
```

The problem is that when I open the jpg images in the saving folder (imm_calibration), they're completely different from the original. Where's the error? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you just copy them as files through the OS?

Comment: Why are you using qt to load, and open cv to save? You can certainly do both operations using either qt or opencv

Comment: Because in another code didn't work! But now using image->save() it works! Thank you very much UmNyobe!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
currentImage->imageData = (char*)image;
```

This is certainly really dubious. you are converting a `QImage*` to a `char*`. First thing to do is to change to

```
currentImage->imageData = image->bits();
```

in order to use the buffer. 
Another thing, you are creating `currentImage` with fixed values, maybe it is better to use

```
cvCreateImageHeader(cv::Size(image->width(),image->height(),....)
```

This is for the qt part. It may still not be enough.